# Is it possible to trigger touch events in other apps?

Tags: android, accessibility

I'm building an app that executes USSD commands automatically. Since we can't execute USSD commands when an USSD dialog is opened, I want to be able to close automatically the USSD dialogs.

Up to now the closest solution I have had is using **Accessibility Service** to get USSD messages and `performGlobalAction` to close the dialog. `performGlobalAction` works (since he returns true when I use it) but clicking on the system Android back button doesn't close USSD dialogs.

PS: I have tested on Android 6.0.

Comment: Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Do you know if in other versions of Android, it's possible to close USSD dialog with BACK button?

Comment: Why don't you just click some button on the dialog rather than performing a `GLOBAL_ACTION_BACK`?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: @Michael Because I don't know how to programmatically click on the dialog buttons. That's the purpose of my question.

Comment: Find the `AccessibilityNodeInfo` corresponding to the button you want to click, then use `performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK)`.

Comment: @Michael Thank you! It works!

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible to do so by using shell commands, you can run shell commands from your own code too. For eg:

adb shell input tap 200 200

it is for terminal.

like these there are many commands to create touch events.